# select from table A when condition is met in table B

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not the best title hence why I was unable to find a solution that would fix mine, point me in the direction if you know of one.

Currently I have the below query,

```
SELECT PRODUCT_NAME
      ,LIVE
      ,LOCATION
FROM PRODUCT_TABLE
WHERE ORDER = 'ONLINE'
AND LIVE = '0' OR '1'
```

This essentially is a really simple query that pulls back a lot of data in which I've been using Excel to drill down to what I need however as I'm sure you can imagine a really tedious process so preferably prefer to do it straight with SQL as I know it can be done just my knowledge has completely disappeared after not using it in a while.

But essentially what I'm wanting to achieve is looking for all products online that are live at a location (0 means YES in the above query) and have matching product name at another location that isn't live (in this case not live = 1).

For example below is some data that is formatted in a similar sort of way.

```
LOCATION    LIVE    PRODUCT_NAME
BERLIN      0       CHAIR
LONDON      1       CHAIR
PARIS       0       LAMP
PARIS       0       SOFA
WARSAW      1       CHAIR
MADRID      0       CHAIR
MANCHESTER  1       SOFA
```

If someone could provide a solution or point me in the right direction that would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
select pt.*
from product_table pt
where pt.live = '0' and
      exists (select 1
              from product_table pt2
              where pt2.product_name = pt.product_name and
                    pt2.location <> pt.location and
                    pt2.live = '1'
             );
```

Comment: `pt2.location <> pt.location` is a little superfluous when we have the checks for `live` but I guess it doesn't hurt to have it.

Comment: @kamilk . . . I thought about that.   The OP doesn't rule out having two rows with the same location and different `live` values.

Comment: Had to change it a tad but essentially it worked, changed where pt.live = '0' to 1 and the select 1 /pt2.live = '1' to 0. I also added AND ORDER = ONLINE= .So this now displays everything that is not live. I probably didn't describe my requirements correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       pt.PRODUCT_NAME
      ,pt.LIVE
      ,pt.LOCATION
FROM PRODUCT_TABLE pt
LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_TABE pt2
    on pt.NAME = pt2.NAME 
        AND pt2.LIVE = 1 
        AND pt.LOCATION != pt2.LOCATION
WHERE pt.ORDER = 'ONLINE'
AND pt.LIVE = '0'
AND pt2.NAME IS NOT NULL
```